# Google Scripts - Move a pacific file to a folder when Cell contains certain text

Tags: google-apps-script

Okay so the plan is to, When a certain cell contains a certain text, it will automaticlly move the file to a pacific folder. Here is what i have, also i am very new to this coding language so im learning at the same time!

Here what i got so far, bearing in mind this does work but ill explain more below:

```
function filemove(root_folder, dest_folderinactive, dest_folderactive) {

var root_folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B_Nz0cop3s-ITTlYM21SNGIwNDg'); 
var dest_folderinactive = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B_Nz0cop3s-IQVZEWUNiQ1d2TzQ');
var dest_folderactive = DriveApp.getFolderById('0B_Nz0cop3s-IalFITGhzN3lTTzg');
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());

var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
if( s.getName() == "StatsData" ) {
var range = s.getRange("E16")
var values = range.getValues();
for(var i in values){
if(values[i][0].match("Not Police")!=null){
  dest_folderinactive.addFile(file);
  root_folder.removeFile(file);
} 
if(values[i][0].match("Police")!=null){
  dest_folderactive.addFile(file);
  root_folder.removeFile(file);
   }
  }
 }
};
```

Okay so what this does is if cell "E16" contains "Not Police" it will move the file to a folder called "Inactive" (dest_folderinactive) and if the cell contains "Police" it will move it to (dest_folderactive) again these both come from the so called "root" folder - i know root means the very fist page of google drive but in this case the base folder which contains these files is named the root. This code works (Sometimes) sometimes you have to run it multiple time for it to actully work and its not very effichant.

My problem also comes when i would like it to do this, When a file is in the In-Active folder and the cell changes to "Police" i would like it to move from In-Active to Active and same for Active saying "non police" to go to inactive but i just can't seem to get this working. It would be greatly helpful if someone could help out, also knowing this code is kinda sheet as it doesn't also do it first time.

Comment: Rather than using `values[i][0].match(string)!=null` to search your trigger cell, consider using `str.search(regEx)>=0`: it's a little more efficient as you're not creating a match object that you don't need. One problem i see is that the word "Police" is present in both searches. Assuming the trigger cell contains only one of "Police" or "Not Police" you can use these searches instead: `values[i][0].search(/^Not Police/)>=0` & `values[i][0].search(/^Police/)>=0`.

Comment: Okay so if i was to use: str.search(regEx)>=0 would u show me how exactly as the way i currently uses works but sometimes it doesnt and requres the script to be run multiple times.

Comment: As i said, change `if(values[i][0].match("Not Police")!=null){` to `if(values[i][0].search(/^Not Police/)>=0){` and change `if(values[i][0].match("Police")!=null){` to `if(values[i][0].search(/^Police/)>=0){` Also, you are going to need to check the file's parents array if you want to move the file from its current folder to another specific folder. You are also declaring your folderID vars in your function declaration, then reinitialising them at the top of the function: is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will move the file to the required folder depending upon the value of your target cell. It will also return the file to the nominated "root" folder if there is junk data in the target cell.  You need to set the specific folder IDs at the top of the code: if you need to pass them in, then you'll need to add them as parameters after `e`.  The parameter `e` is required to consume the `onEdit` trigger event data (which this function doesn't use, but you would need to account for if you are passing in the folder IDs).

```
function filemove(e){
  // folder IDs
  var root_folder = 'root_folder_id_string';
  var dest_folderinactive = 'inactive_files_folder_id_string';
  var dest_folderactive = 'active_files_folder_id_string';

  // the specific destination folder on this run
  var dest_folder;
  // assume the file will move
  var move_file = true;

  // the spreadsheet & its parent folders
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId());
  var parents = file.getParents();
  var sheet = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName("StatsData"));

  // now grab the value of E16 & look for the string "police"
  // string.search(regEx) returns the position of the first match, otherwise -1
  var values = sheet.getRange("E16").getValues();
  switch(values[0][0].search(/police/i)){
    case -1:
      dest_folder = root_folder;
      break;
    case 0:
      dest_folder = dest_folderactive;
      break;
    default:
      dest_folder = dest_folderinactive;
  }

  // is the dest_folder in the parents array?
  while(parents.hasNext()){
    var fldr = parents.next().getId();
    if(fldr == dest_folder){
      // YES -- don't move the file
      move_file = false;
    } else{
      // NO -- are the other folders in the parents array?
      if(fldr == root_folder || fldr == dest_folderinactive || fldr == dest_folderactive){
        // YES -- remove the file from that folder
        DriveApp.getFolderById(fldr).removeFile(file);
      }
    }
  }

  // do we have to move the file?
  if(move_file){
    DriveApp.getFolderById(dest_folder).addFile(file);
  }
}
```

I'm stepping over the parents array & comparing them to the destination folders so that you don't remove the file from another folder by mistake.

If the target cell has more free-form data & you are looking for the string "police" or "not police", then the `switch()` will not work. In this case you will need to use `if(...){...} else if(...){...} else{...}` to test.